# How to use a for loop to blit a list images to the screen in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, blackjack

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5GZN.jpg 
Im trying to use a for loop to blit a list of cards to the screen in pygame. im not sure if the way im doing it is correct but i cant think of anyother way of doing it. The image shows the problem, its repeating the second card in the list and i dont know why. 
just for some context for the code below. players is a list of Player() objects. One of the attributes of the player object is Hand, Hand is a list of Card() objects which have and image attribute. I'm able to blit them to the screen individually but when i try and use a for loop it copies the second card. I have no idea why.

Im able to individually blit the images but the problem occurs when i try to use a for loop.

```py
def game():


    global start
    deck = Deck()
    deck.create_deck()
    deck.shuffle()
    deck.deal()


    seats = [

     (50,250),(60,265),    #seat 1
     (175,380),(185,395),  #seat 2 
     (300,450),(310,465),  #seat 3
     (400,450),(410,465),  #seat 4 
     (600,465),(610,480),  #seat 5
     (730,375),(740,390)   #seat 6

     ]


    win.blit(table,(0,0))
    index = 0
    while game_on:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        if start:

            for player in players:
                win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(player.hand[0].img,(card_size)),(seats[index]))

                if index == 0:
                    index = 1


                win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(player.hand[0].img,(card_size)),(seats[index]))


        index+=1

        if index >= 2*len(players):
            start = False
```

Comment: Are you sure cards are dealed correctly?

Answer (score 0):

```
seats = [

 ((50,250),(60,265)),    #seat 1
 ((175,380),(185,395)),  #seat 2 
 ((300,450),(310,465)),  #seat 3
 ((400,450),(410,465)),  #seat 4 
 ((600,465),(610,480)),  #seat 5
 ((730,375),(740,390))   #seat 6

 ]

# ...

            win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(player.hand[0].img,(card_size)),(seats[index][0]))
            win.blit(pygame.transform.scale(player.hand[0].img,(card_size)),(seats[index][1]))
```